# Search by composite field at the View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in my SQL Server database. One of the columns in this view is the composite column.

```
ng.NAGS_GLASS_ID + ' ' + npp.GLASS_COLOR_CD + npp.ATCHMNT_FLAG AS PART_NUMBER
```

So, `Part_Number field comes from 2 different tables and is aggregated into a string.

My question is: is it OK to search by this column?

The thing that I am afraid of is that SQL Server will need to build `Part_Number` from all tables in the database and only after this apply `WHERE` condition.

Comment: . . Your description of how the code works pretty much explains what will happen.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You could search by that field but it is being recalculated all the time, as part of the view. So that's not going to be great performance-wise.

You'll get way better performance by querying on the columns separately, even in the same WHERE clause, as SQL Server can then apply each predicate to the appropriate underlying tables.